# Splitting number by divider

Tags: python

I wanted to make a function that easily split a number by its divider and returns the quotient and remainder the following way:

```py
[6,6,6,3] = function(21, 6)
[2,2,2] = function(6,2)
```

I use a while loop counting until i reach zero:

```
divider = 6
start = 21
ret = []
while start >= divider:
    ret.append(divider)
    start -= divider
if start:
    ret.append(start)
```

I was wondering if there was a more easier/pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just calculate, using e.g. floor division and modulo:

```
def function(n, d):
    return [d] * (n // d) + [n%d] if n%d else []

>>> function(21, 6)
[6, 6, 6, 3]
>>> function(6, 2)
[2, 2, 2]
```

There is also the built-in `divmod` function, that calculates both in one step:

```
def function(n, d):
    div, mod = divmod(n, d)
    return div * [d] + bool(mod) * [mod]
```

Comment: thanks i always forget to remember that the [x] * y syntax exists

Comment: Not the worst thing to forget ;-) once you deal with more complex (mutable) objects, that syntax feature comes with plenty of gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```py
def function(a, b):
    result = []
    for x in range(a//b):
        result.append(b)
    if a % b != 0:
        result.append(a % b)
    return result
```